# How to update to PhpStorm 2018

Tags: phpstorm

I am quite new with Ubuntu and I am using PhpStorm for writing code.

Can you please tell me how to update it from 2017.3.4 to 2018.1 without losing setup?

Comment: *(for 2017.3)* How did you install it on first place? **1)** JetBrains has [Toolbox App](http://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/) that can be used for downloading/upgrading any of their apps, including upcoming/EAP versions. **2)** Have you tried the most obvious `Help | Check for Updates...` in PhpStorm? **3)**  (for current stable 2017.3.x) You can download latest version from [their website](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/) and install as usual (remove previous version and install into empty folder).

Comment: *(for 2018.1)* On first launch of new major version .. IDE will ask what to do with the setting: it will see that you have settings fro 2017.3 and will offer to import them. Each major version uses different folder(s) to store their settings .. so you can run multiple major versions in parallel.

Comment: Ok thanks that is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the latest official version of phpstorm is Version 2017.3.6.

Version 2018 is only a preview. You can download the preview here: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/download-thanks.html?type=eap&platform=linux

Comment: Ok thanks and anyway how to update from 2017.3.4 to 2017.3.6 ?